# replace domain and path of image

Tags: php, regex

I have moved my image server to a different location. how can I replace the domain and path only in the < img > tag without touching the < a > tag

```
<img src="http://old-domain.com/bad/old/smiley.gif" height="42" width="42">
```

into

```
<img src="http://new-domain.com/good/new/smiley.gif" height="42" width="42">
```

I have been trying to get this with no luck

```
$pattern = '/(<img [^>]*>)/i';
$replacement = 'hello' . '\1world';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Comment: Is using a DOM parser instead of a regex an option for you? The XPath would be quite simple... but it depends on whether you have (semi-)valid HTML documents/snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this to find the relevant pieces:

```
'/<img [^>]*src=\"http://old-domain.com\/bad\/old(?:[^"]*)"/i'
```

This is looking for `img` tags that contain the bad domains.

Use this with [preg_replace_callback](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) where the callback function does a simple [str_replace](http://nz1.php.net/str_replace) of the old path with the correct one.

Or if you want to look for all image tags or the domain changes, then just:

```
'/<img [^>]*src=\"http:/(?:[^"]*)"/i'
```

And adjust the replacement function to find the domain part.

Note that it'll only work if you're using double quotes for the attribute, but I'm sure you can adapt as needed.

Comment: old-domain.com/bad/old i need a regex because each path is different and also domains

Comment: @XK8ER updated answer then. you didn't provide much info on what was wrong, just that you had "no luck". No much to go on :/

Comment: maybe, lets try a different approach.. how can I extract the image name from the < img > tag

Answer (score 1):

## Try this method:

```
$pattern = '/(<img.*?)(old-domain.com/bad/old)(.*?[^>]*>)/i';
$replacement = '\1new-domain/good/new\3';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

### Regex explained:

`(<img.*?)(old-domain.com/bad/old)(.*?[^>]*>)`

- **Entire match:** Captures the IMG tag, without matching the closing tag (`</img>`)
- **Capture group 1:** The beginning of the img tag
- **Capture group 2:** The old domain
- **Capture group 3:** The closing `>`